# Saving data to 2 tables in the database in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a simple sample project created to test how to add data to 2 tables from one controller in `CakePHP`, I have a tables called `Student`, `Users`, `Admin` and `UserGroups`. I need to add a Student to the database table and also add the students username and password to the users table. Here are the SQL for the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `admins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I created the following function to add the data to the `Students` table and the `Users` table.

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                    $userGrp = $this->request->data['Student']['user_group_id'];
                    $username = $this->request->data['Student']['username'];
                    $pass = $this->request->data['Student']['password'];

            $this->Student->create();
            if ($this->Student->save($this->request->data)) {
                                $this->request->data['User']['user_group_id'] = $userGrp;
                                $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $username;
                                $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $pass;
                                if ($this->Student->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student has been saved. Both in to Student and User'));
                                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                                }

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $userGroups = $this->Student->UserGroup->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('userGroups'));
    }
```

The model for the Student is as follows.

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Student extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'name';

    public $belongsTo = array(
            'UserGroup' => array(
                    'className' => 'UserGroup',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_group_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
            )
    );

}
```

When i add the Student details in to the database following error shows. Data is sent to the Student table but not to the Users table

```
Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
File: D:\wamp\www\MultiTables\app\Controller\StudentsController.php
```

What am i doing wrong here? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, students and admins should all be in a table called 'users'.
Your table that you named "users" is really a join table.  That is an incorrect name for a join table if you are following conventions.

Then you would have these models:

- Users (belongsTo UserGroups)
- UserGroups (habtm Users via UserGroupUsers)
- UserGroupUsers (belongsTo Users & belongsTo UserGroups)

If linked like that, then these inputs would save data to all three tables:

`$this->Form->input('User.username')`

`$this->Form->input('User.password')`

`$this->Form->input('UserGroup.id', array('value' => 15)`

You should check out CakePHP's "bake" feature.  If you give it a properly constructed database, it will help you make correctly linked models.

Seems that what you're currently trying to do is:

- Students (belongsTo Users)
- UserGroups (habtm Students via Users & habtm Admins via Users)
- Users (belongsTo Students & belongsTo Users & belongsTo Admins)

`$this->Form->input('Student.username')`

`$this->Form->input('User.password')`

`$this->Form->input('UserGroup.id', array('value' => 15)`

Answer (score 0):

Model Student is not associated with model User.
So when you do `$this->Student->User->save()` with no association defined in the Student Model, You will afterwards get the error you showed because `Student` does not know about `User`.

Try defining a model Association between Student and User Model like this: A student belongs to the User and a User belongs to a UserGroup

```
class Student extends AppModel {

public $displayField = 'name';

public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
        )
);
```

}

```
class User extends AppModel {



public $belongsTo = array(
        'UserGroup' => array(
                'className' => 'UserGroup',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_group_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
        )
);
```

}

This assumes then that you rename your `Student.user_group_id` into a `Student.user_id` in your database. Now if you want to save the User from the Student controller you can either use:

- `$this->Student->User->save($this->request->data)`
- or use the `saveAssociated()` method like this `$this->Student->saveAssociated($this->request->data)` if you named your form fields correctly